# facebook invite friends for Unity через FB.AppRequest

Tags: c#, unity3d, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Задача: сделать инвайт друзьям в facebook на игру в unity.
facebook sdk для Unity импортирован, в facebook Edit Settings в Unity все настроено. Настроен FB.Init() и вход в игру через facebook. В Аккаунте разработчика создано приложение и все поля заполнены, созданы тестовые пользователи, для них настроены разрешения public_profile. При вызове метода FB.AppRequest появляется диалоговое окно с выбором друзей и кнопка отправить, при отправке в callback не приходит никаких ошибок, все проходит четко, но сам invate не приходит. Пробовал тестировать на тестовых пользователях, на администраторах, на тестовых с администраторами, пробовал тесты в режиме разработки и в рабочем режиме(Опубликованном), ничего не меняется, invate так и не приходит, в чем может быть ошибка? буду благодарен любой помощи.